# Updating existing features in PostGIS using QGIS processing model

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing

When writing to PostGIS using a QGIS processing model, I don´t see an option for updating existing features, just adding new ones.

Is this use case covered in QGIS?

Comment: What would be your criterion to know which feature(s) should be updated? An id (i.e., any field you choose as 'id') comparison?

Comment: Yes, using a shared id field.

Comment: Have a look at the [AppendFeaturesToLayer](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer/) plugin. It allows you to set a common field to match features between source and target layers. You can also set the behavior for common features found: skip (leave the existing feature as it is) or update (replace it with new values).